# Private constructor in C#

Tags: c#, constructor, private

I am reading *Beginning Visual C# 2012*.

Consider:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Ch10Ex01
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public readonly string Name;
        private int intVal;

        public int Val
        {
            get { return intVal; }
            set
            {
                if (0 <= value && value <= 10)
                    intVal = value;
                else
                    throw (new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Val", value,
                        "Val must be assigned a value between 0 and 10."));
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Name: " + Name + "\nVal: " + Val;
        }

        private MyClass() : this("Default Name")
        {
        }

        public MyClass(string newName)
        {
            Name = newName;
            intVal = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation in the book: Note that I've used this ("Default Name") to ensure that Name gets a value if this constructor ever gets called, which is possible if this class is used to derive a new class. This is necessary as not assigning a value to the Name field could be a source of errors later.

What's puzzling me: How can it be used in a derived class as it's "private"? What does this ("Default Name") mean? How does the object get the "Default Name" as its name?

Comment: "_see the comments_". What comments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What's puzzling me: How can it be used in a derived class as it's "private"? What does this("Default Name") mean? **How does the object get the "Default Name" as its name?

You are right to be puzzled!

That code sample does not call the default constructor at all - and because it is private, nothing else can call it without using reflection (not even a derived class; it would have to be at least `protected` for a derived class to call it - or the derived class would have to be nested within the base class).

In the sample code, the object does *not* get "Default Name" as its value.

So it's a typo or an error in the book.

The correct solution to what the book is describing is to:

1. Omit the default constructor altogether.
2. Initialise `Name` at field scope. This ensures that it is impossible to fail to initialise it, no matter what other constructors are written in this or any derived class.

Like so:

```
class MyClass
{
    public readonly string Name = "Default Name";
    private int intVal;

    public int Val
    {
        get
        {
            return intVal;
        }
        set
        {
            if (0 <= value && value <= 10)
                intVal = value;
            else
                throw (new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Val", value,
                    "Val must be assigned a value between 0 and 10."));
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Name: " + Name + "\nVal: " + Val;
    }

    public MyClass(string newName)
    {
        Name = newName;
        intVal = 0;
    }
}
```

Note that it can often be useful to declare a private default constructor which is called by other constructors - but the declaring class *has to actually use it*.

Also note that if you declare a non-default constructor in a base class and do not declare a default constructor at all, any derived class *must* call one of the existing base class constructors.

For example given the class definition above, then both the following class declarations will cause a compile error `MyClass' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`:

```
class MyDerivedClass1: MyClass
{
    public MyDerivedClass1()  // Compile error
    {
    }
}

class MyDerivedClass2: MyClass
{
    // No constructor declared at all. Also a compile error.
}
```

To fix the error, `MyDerivedClass` has to call an existing constructor:

```
class MyDerivedClass: MyClass
{
    public MyDerivedClass(): base("My new name")
    {
    }
}
```

**So what use *is* a private constructor**

A fairly typical use is to put common initialisation code into a default constructor. Sometimes, however, you don't want the caller to be able to default-construct the type - in which case you can make the default constructor private.

That way, you can still use the default constructor for common initialisation but you prevent code outside the class from doing it, for example:

```
class Test
{
    public readonly int IntValue;
    public readonly string StringValue;

    private Test()
    {
        // Do common initialisation.
    }

    public Test(int intValue): this()
    {
        IntValue = intValue;
    }

    public Test(string stringValue): this()
    {
        StringValue = stringValue;
    }
}
```

Often you could just use a private `init()` method to do the common initialisation, but if you are initialising a `readonly` field you *must* use a constructor to do so. In that case, a private constructor must be used instead of an `init()` method.

Another use of a private default constructor is to prevent any instantiation of the type at all (you just declare a private default constructor and no other constructors at all).

In .Net 1.x that was the only way to do so - but subsequent versions of .Net introduced static classes which for most cases removed the need to use a private constructor for that type.

You might also declare a private constructor to force the use of a static factory method to instantiate the type.

---

Just for completeness, here's a contrived example that demonstrates how a private constructor *can* be called from a nested derived class:

```
class OuterClass
{
    public readonly string Value;

    private OuterClass(): this("Default Value")
    {
    }

    public OuterClass(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public OuterClass GetInnerClass()
    {
        return new InnerClass();
    }

    private class InnerClass: OuterClass
    {
    }
}
```

With that class definition, the following code will print "Default Value":

```
OuterClass test = new OuterClass("Test");
Console.WriteLine(test.GetInnerClass().Value);
```

Personally I've never had to write a nested class that derives from its containing class, but it's possible if you need to do it for some reason.

Comment: As usual, the impossible becomes possible using reflection: `System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` bypasses constructors and field initializers.

Answer (score 0):

Because this class has a `private` constructor, the ONLY way that the constructor can be called is within this particular class. Not even a derived class can call it (if it was `protected` then it could). As your code example shows, this serves no purpose.

The reason why it's a default constructor calling another is just a way of having a hard-coded default value without the user knowing/caring what it is. This is similar to default parameters for functions in .NET 4.0.

To me, it would make much more sense to make both constructors public, because I don't see any code that uses the default constructor (if you have shown us all the code).

---

There are some legitimate reasons to use private constructors, specifically with static functions or sub-classes. Take the following for example:

```
public class OuterClass
{
    private OuterClass() {  }

    public static OuterClass GetOuter() { return new OuterClass(); }   
}
```

In this way, you can only make a new instance of the class from the static method.

Comment: Your statement is not quite correct. A derived class can invoke a private constructor if the derived class is nested within the base class.

Comment: @EricLippert, you are correct, which is why I mentioned sub-classes (nested classes) as an exception. When I think of derived classes, I think of classes in different code files.

Comment: You are misusing the term "subclass". A subclass is a derived class -- and its superclass is its base class. A nested class is a class lexically inside another class -- they are usually called the "inner" and "outer" classes, but be careful with that; by "inner class" many people mean a Java-style inner class, bound to an instance of the outer class. C# does not support that kind of inner class by default.

Answer (score 0):

A private constructor means a user can not directly instantiate a class. Instead, you can create objects using something like the named constructor Idiom, where you have static class functions that can create and return instances of a class. You can use the private constructor to control the instantion of the Object usually used in the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

You have to read the singleton pattern to understand the purpose of the private constructor.